# Buttons & Actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm fairly new to rails and so far it's been great but now I'm stuck.
Here's what I want to do as an example:

A view displays an array of numbers from the corresponding controller. Underneath is a button. When a user clicks the button a method in the controller should be activated which sorts the array and then displays the sorted array back in the view.

What is the best way of doing something like this in rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By example you can reuse the same controller action that you have used to display the original array and send an additional `:sorted` parameter when the button is clicked, in the controller you return the sorted array if the param exists:

```
@array.sort! if params[:sorted]
```

Using `sort!` will modify your original array object, i don't know if this is acceptable for you otherwise using `sort` will return a sorted copy of your array.

Bests,

Richard

Comment: Thanks! But what would be the code for the button in the view? And also, does the user have to manually refresh the page to see the sorted array?

Comment: Concerning the code for the button what is the name of your controller and the name of the action you are using to display the original array ? Yes if you display a button to refresh the page the user will have to manually click on it. I don't really know what you are trying to do, so maybe you should give us more information and/or show some existing code.